# Split string into parts by multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some kind of string to split into array by different conditions. I have tried different ways of doing that. But still is won't as expected.

My string can contain any character.
Note: string does not contain spaces

Example string :- 
`$$_hello_$$-world/foo/$$_bar_$$$$_john_$$-doe`

I need to split as,

1. `$$_anythinghere_$$` is one part
2. `-` another part
3. `/` another part
4. any other texts as another part

I want to split this string to an array like

`["$$_hello_$$", "-", "world", "/", "foo", "/", "$$_bar_$$", "$$_john_$$", "-", "doe"]`

I expect a solution in vanilla javascript.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: 4th item is not clear. could you please clarify what you expect as a separator besides the first 3 items?

Comment: Make each split criteria as a regular expression and then concatenate them all into a single string that's delimited by `|`.  Use that regular expression to split your string.  Without you posting any code that's the answer to what you've asked.

Comment: Can you add the code that you tried to the question?

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```
var regex = new RegExp(/(\$\$\_(.*?)\_\$\$)|(\-)|(\/)|((?:.)\w*)/, 'ig');
var str = "$$_hello_$$-world/foo/$$_bar_$$$$_john_$$-doe";
var matches = [];


while (i = regex.exec(str)) {
    matches.push(i[0]);
}

console.log(matches)
```